# Save to file and load an instance of a python class with its attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance, pickle

I am working with python to do data analysis and was hoping to find a good way to save an instance of a class to file so it can be reloaded later with the values of its attributes maintained. In particular, an instance of this class will load objects that are instances of other classes, then do processor intensive comparisons that take a while to complete.

For instance:

```
import pickle

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.info = OtherClass(option=1)

    def pickle(self):
        f = file('test_file', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        f.close()

    def unpickle(self):
        f = file('test_file', 'rb')
        pickle.load(f)
        f.close()


class OtherClass():
    def __init__(self, option):
        self.property = option * 2


mydata = MyClass(option=5)

mydata.pickle()
```

Then later import this module and run mydata.unpickle() to get mydata back (I also have an option that looks for if the file has been pickled before and suspends the calculation and calling of the OtherClass instance if it has).
Right now, if I do this I can load mydata, but it no longer has the mydata.info object. My understanding is that this is an intentional part of pickle, but is there a way to save mydata completely so that I can use it later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing nothing with the data you've loaded.

```
class MyClass():
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def unpickle():
        with file('test_file', 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)

data = MyClass.unpickle()
```

Comment: Ah geeze. Yep, that's all it was. Thanks.